# Making tmux do idle timeouts?

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to configure tmux to kill an idle session?  I connect to a server with:

```
ssh -t host-name tmux new -A -s session-name
```

Most of the time, I want tmux to keep the session nailed up even if my ssh connection dies.  This protects me against transient issues like my desktop crashing.  That is, of course, the reason tmux exists.

But if I've simply forgotten to log out, I'd like the session to get killed after a sufficiently long idle time (say, 24 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `tmux` with `TMOUT=NUMBER_SECONDS` set in your environment.

> TMOUT is an environmental setting that determines the timeout of a shell in seconds.